# Removing the line indentation from verses and choruses in a song

Tags: indentation, songs

Friends, consider the following code using the [`songs`](http://songs.sourceforge.net/) package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[lyric]{songs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\chorusfont}{\bfseries}

\newindex{titleidx}{cbtitle}

\begin{document}

\showindex{My index}{titleidx}

\begin{songs}{titleidx}

\beginsong{My cool song}[
  by={John Doe}]

\beginchorus
\lipsum[4]
\endchorus

\beginverse
\lipsum[4]
\endverse

\endsong

\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

I'm stuck with this line identation from both choruses and verses:

[image: Songs]

I'd like to make the subsequent lines aligned with the first line of the group. I tried to alter the `\versenumwidth` lenght, but it defines the horizontal space reserved for verse numbers to the left. Besides, there is the chorus indentation as well, which I couldn't find anything meaningful.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lengths involved are `\leftskip` and `\parindent` which are used by the command `\justifyleft` which, in is turn, is used by `\versejustify` and `\chorusjustify`. One possible solution would be then to redefine `\justifyleft`, but perhaps the original definition would be needed somewhere else, so I opted for defining a new command (which I called `\myjustify`) to be used by `\versejustify` and `\chorusjustify` producing the desired result:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[lyric]{songs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\chorusfont}{\bfseries}

\newindex{titleidx}{cbtitle}

\makeatletter
 \newcommand\myjustify{%%
 \ifSB@inverse\advance\leftskip\versenumwidth\fi%
 \SB@cbarshift%
 \parindent0pt
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\versejustify{\myjustify}
\renewcommand\chorusjustify{\myjustify}

\begin{document}

\showindex{My index}{titleidx}

\begin{songs}{titleidx}

\beginsong{My cool song}[
  by={John Doe}]

\beginchorus
\lipsum[4]
\endchorus

\beginverse
\lipsum[3]
\endverse

\endsong

\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, @Gonzalo! I managed to make verses work with `\parindent`, but failed when dealing with choruses. Your code is very intuitive and elegant, thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if this is intended behaviour for the package. Song lyrics are divided into lines (or so it assumes), which are indented if they spill over into more than one line on the page. Unlike standard TeX, inside the songs environment line breaks *are* significant. So all you need to do is decide where you want the lines to break, and write something like

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[lyric]{songs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\chorusfont}{\bfseries}

\newindex{titleidx}{cbtitle}

\begin{document}

\showindex{My index}{titleidx}

\begin{songs}{titleidx}

\beginsong{My cool song}[
  by={John Doe}]

\beginchorus
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit.
This is a very long line which is going to break if I'm not careful.
\endchorus

\beginverse
Here we go round the mulberry bush,
Mulberry bush, mulberry bush.
\endverse

\endsong

\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

But if you still don't want any indentation, even on the broken line,

```
\parindent=0pt
```

is your friend.

Comment: Thanks @Ant for mentioning it. `=)` These line breaks serve a good purpose. I usually stick with the default parameters (and I'm happy with them), but in this particular case I had to make an exception. We are finishing a pocket songbook and the indentation takes a significant amount of space (altering the `\versenumwidth` lenght does not look good at all. `=(` ). I'll try `\parindent` as you suggested.